# How to set launcher icon in android in API version greater than 25

Tags: android

How do I generate Android app launcher icon?

My Manifest file of my android app:

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1. In mipmap folder I see many file for `ic_launcher`. Which file to change for the launcher icon?

Comment: what do you mean by this you are already doing the correct thing.

Comment: My question about how to generate launcher icon

Comment: you can use photoshop or any tool to create launcher icon and then put it into mipmap or drawable folder.

Comment: I am using android Studio 3.0.1. In mipmap folder i see many file for ic_launcher. Which file will be change?

Answer (score 1):

Android requires different sizes for same icon so that it can automatically check which size is required for which device.

To add custom `launcher icon` to your app you have to create a icon with different sizes and add your them in mipmap folder.

Now change the icon name  in menifiest file 
for example you add a image named my_appicon.png and your roundedIcon name is my_appicon_round.png then in menifiest file

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/my_appicon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/my_appicon_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

the roundIcon can also be same but if you want to provide round icon for your app you can do this using 
roundIcon property.

Note: different image sizes are not compulsary android can auto resize your images to different sizes if you don't provide them.